# Mongo Sharding got trouble when using vmware

Tags: mongodb

Mongo worked fine when i'm using the local machine.But when i add the shard(established on vmware),i can't do insert operation anymore.
error message:

```
 caused by :: Location28563 cannot send batch write operation to server 192.168.153.132:3000 (192.168.153.132)'. (Response was { "err" : "write results unavailable from 192.168.153.132:3000 :: caused by :: Location28563 cannot send batch write operation to server
```

config server setup command:
mongod --dbpath=config --port 2222 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0

route server setup command:
mongos --port 3333 --configdb=192.168.153.1:2222 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0

shard server setup command:
mongod --dbpath=Shard1 --port 4444 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0

And i'd done addShard command on the route server.

Comment: What is "Shard1" in your dbpath? That appears to be one error. "mongod --dbpath=Shard1 --port 4444 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0"

Comment: Shard1 is a directory under the current directory.